# Clip and export PostGIS polygon to GeoTIFF

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

I have a Multipolygon layer in a PostGIS database which essentially makes a gridded data field.

I want to clip this data using a bounding box and the clipped data should include all the polygons with which the bounding box intersects. This I can do with the following code:

```
import psycopg
conn = psycopg.connect(dbname = db, user = username, password = passp, host = host_ad, sslmode = "prefer")

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    sql  = "SELECT * FROM WHERE shape && ST_GeomFromText('SRID=25832;POLYGON(({} {}, {} {}, {} {}, {} {}, {} {} ))')".format(inlayer, minx, miny, maxx, miny, maxx, maxy, minx, maxy, minx, miny)
```

Once the data has been clipped, how can I rasterize the data and export it as a multiband GeoTIFF where each field is saved in a different band?

Answer (score 1):

Use st_asraster - [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) - chained with st_asgdalraster - [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsGDALRaster.html).

```
SELECT ST_AsGDALRaster(rast, 'GTiff') As rastgtiff
from (select ST_AsRaster(
        ST_Buffer(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(50 50,150 150,150 50)'), 10,'join=bevel'),
            200,200,ARRAY['8BUI', '8BUI', '8BUI'], ARRAY[118,154,118], ARRAY[0,0,0]) rast
      ) foo;
```